# Trying to sort an array of numbers java

Tags: java, sorting, vector, syntax, void

So I'm trying to sort an array (or vector. In my country it's called vector, but yeah) with a pretty easy algorithm. The language is Java and I'm using Eclipse. Nothing fancy, I know there are much more effective algorithms for sorting but that's not what I need now. Here's the code:

```
public void SortMethod(nbrs) {
int nbrs[];
int v[];

public void sort() {
    this.nbrs = nbrs;
    this.v=v;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int minIndex = -1;
        for (int k = i; k < 10; k++) {
            if (nbrs[k] < min) {
                min = nbrs[k];
                minIndex = k;
            }
        }
        v[minIndex] = v[i];
        v[i] = min;
    }
}

}
```

And in another project I have:

```
public class Vector {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int nbrs[] = {2, 4, 67, 40, 32, 28, 9, 8, 55, 72 };

    nbrs.sort();

    for(int j = 0; j<10; j++){
        System.out.println(nbrs[j]);
    }
}
}
```

In the sorting method I get errors at the "void" part in

```
public void SortMethod(nbrs) {
```

at the "void" saying that @ is expected, and "Syntax error, insert Interface-identifier to complete InterfaceHeader.

Also I get error at

```
nbrs.sort();
```

In the Vector class.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. You should declare variable of SortMethod class and then use it's method.

Comment: A lot of things are wrong in your code. I think you should first thoroughly understand how classes, objects, methods and method parameters work in Java before continuing : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Comment: Yes, I can see that now. Now that it's been pointed out to me, the mistakes are quite obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry... you can't simply pass `nbrs` in the method (here, appropriately, constructor) signature. You need to declare what data type it is...

```
public class SortMethod {

    int[] nbrs;
    // ... the other fields.

    // This is a 'Constructor'
    public SortMethod (int[] nbrs) {
        this.nbrs = nbrs;
    }
```

Next, in your *invocation* of `sort()`, you should use something like:

```
// ...
SortMethod sMethod = new SortMethod(nbrs);
sMethod.sort();
// ...
```

---

More appropriately, you could create a `static` method that sorts the array, which implies **no need for object creation for a trivial task**:

```
public static void sort (int[] nbrs) {
    // ... code here.
}
```

and you can call it as:

```
// ...
<class_Name>.sort(nbrs); // from any where within the same package without an import.
// ...
```

---

TIP: You can try using the library method for your implementation:

```
// ...
java.util.Arrays.sort (nbrs);
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you for thorough and pedagogic answer.

Comment: So, because of `public static void` I don't need to create an object of the parameters? As opposed to `public void`?

Comment: @user3535325 Yes... I'd recommend that you download the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

`public void SortMethod` needs to be changed to

```
public class SortMethod {

     //provide getters and setters for nbrs if required
     public void sort(int[] nbrs) {
        ...
     }
}
```

And following changes are needed in Vector class:

```
public class Vector {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int nbrs[] = {2, 4, 67, 40, 32, 28, 9, 8, 55, 72 };

    SortMethod sortNumbers = new SortMethod();
    sortNumbers.sort(nbrs);

    for(int j = 0; j<10; j++){
        System.out.println(nbrs[j]);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reworked your code a bit, so it actually works:

```
public class SortMethod {
    public static void sort(int[] nbrs) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            int minIndex = -1;
            for (int k = i; k < 10; k++) {
                if (nbrs[k] < min) {
                    min = nbrs[k];
                    minIndex = k;
                }
            }
            nbrs[minIndex] = nbrs[i];
            nbrs[i] = min;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Vector {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int nbrs[] = { 2, 4, 67, 40, 32, 28, 9, 8, 55, 72 };

        SortMethod.sort(nbrs);

        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            System.out.println(nbrs[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, this sorting method is called "Selection Sort" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
    import java.util.Arrays;

    Arrays.sort(nbrs);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nbrs));
```

Comment: I know that method, but I want to learn it do this way as well. Thanks though!